# Why should I use the InkCanvas in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing, canvas, inkcanvas

In my WPF application I have some drawing functionality. I have solved this using a Canvas and handling mouse gestures manually, and I also add the drawn Strokes (wrapped in InkPresenter) to this Canvas.

Using Blend I suddenly discover that there is something called **InkCanvas**. According to Blend this is a control that *"Defines an area that receives and displays ink strokes."*, so it sounds relevant to what I do. But everything seems to work fine using a plain Canvas..

So; how does the InkCanvas differ from the plain Canvas, and why should I choose to use this instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They really are meant to serve two different purposes. `Canvas` is for layout. Specifically for more exact control over layout using absolute positioning. `InkCanvas` is, as you know, for capturing and displaying strokes.

What you are doing is just fine, but `InkCanvas` has some nice additional features like `EditMode` among others. It is meant to save you from writing a lot of the stuff you would have to do by hand using `Canvas`. Using `Canvas` is a roll your own kind of approach where `InkCanvas` is a use a pre-built in kind of approach.

Comment: @Jeff Yates - Thanks! I must have typed server out of force of habit.

Answer (score 8):

An InkCanvas handles the mouse events for you to draw on the canvas. It also has this functionality:

- Save/Load

  Resize/Scale

  Highlight behind text

  Eraser mode

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/inkcanvas_pg1.htm

Answer (score 4):

When performance in concerned, InkCanvas with real mouse events is much faster than creating a stroke out of StylusPointCollection, I found that adding new points to a StylusPointCollection is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 2):

we can develop whiteboard application,paint application using InkCanvas WPF.
EditMode gives us so many features like
Gestures,drawing,,erasing,multi touch operations,select element drag drop options.
insert elements like shapes,images,videos,stroke annotations
we can save/load all strokes and elements.
we can customise InkCanvas class.